# Postgres tags list and tag filtering

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables

```
users table:
    +---------+---------+
    | id      |  name   |
    +---------+---------+
    | 1       | James   |
    | 2       | Carl    |
    | 3       | Bob     |
    | 4       | Steve   |
    | 5       | Evan    |
    +---------+---------+

tags table:
    +---------+---------+
    | id      | name    |
    +---------+---------+
    | 1       | Travel  |
    | 2       | Food    |
    | 3       | Fitness |
    +---------+---------+

usertag table:
    +----------+----------+
    | user_id  |  tag_id  |
    +----------+----------+
    | 1        | 1        |
    | 2        | 2        |
    | 1        | 3        |
    | 3        | 2        |
    | 3        | 1        |
    | 4        | 3        |
    | 5        | 1        |
    +----------+----------+
```

I made a query that fetches all the users and their tags in a comma-separated field

```
SELECT users.*, ARRAY_AGG(usertag.tag_id) as tags
FROM users
JOIN usertags on users.id = usertag.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Which gives me the result:

```
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | id      |  name   | tags     |
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | 1       | James   | [1,3]    |
    | 2       | Carl    | [2]      |
    | 3       | Bob     | [2,1]    |
    | 4       | Steve   | [3]      |
    | 5       | Evan    | [1]      |
    +---------+---------+----------+
```

What I need to do next is filter by tags. Very much an all-or-nothing type of filtering. So if I want a user with tags of 1 and 3, I should only get back James. Even though Steve, Bob, and Evan have tags 1 or 3, only James has the combination of 1 and 3.

I tried the following but it doesn't give me the results I expect

```
SELECT users.*, ARRAY_AGG(usertags.tag_id) as tags
FROM users
JOIN usertags on users.id = usertags.user_id
WHERE usertags.tag_id IN (1,3)
GROUP BY users.id
```

But I get this back

```
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | id      |  name   | tags     |
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | 1       | James   | [3,1]    |
    | 3       | Bob     | [1]      |
    | 4       | Steve   | [3]      |
    | 5       | Evan    | [1]      |
    +---------+---------+----------+
```

When I would really just like to get the users that have all those tags. In this case, it would be one user, James.

```
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | id      |  name   | tags     |
    +---------+---------+----------+
    | 1       | James   | [3,1]    |
    +---------+---------+----------+
```

How can I change this query to make it an all-or-nothing type of filtering where I pass in any number of tag ids?

UPDATE:

I should have been a little more clear. Say I pass in tags [1], then I would like all users that have tag 1 even if they have something else. However, if I check for tags [1,3], then I want only users that have tags 1 and 3 present in their tags list. So if I check for [1,3], I don't want users back that have JUST 1 in their tags list. And say I pass in [1,2,3] as tags, then I don't want users that have just [1,3] in their tags list but all users that have [1,2,3] even if they have others that aren't asked for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the users you have *at least* those two tags, you can use the overlaps operator `&&`

```
SELECT u.*, ARRAY_AGG(ut.tag_id) AS tags
FROM users u
  JOIN usertags ut ON u.id = ut.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(ut.tag_id) && array[1,3];
```

If you need those users that have **exactly** those two tag (not more), then you can either an equality condition:

```
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(ut.tag_id order by ut.tag_id) = array[1,3];
```

Note the `order by` to make the order in both arrays identical.
Alternatively you can combine the `@>` and `<@` operators

```
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(ut.tag_id) @> array[1,3]
   AND ARRAY_AGG(ut.tag_id) <@ array[1,3]
```

Comment: This is great! The only issue is say I pass in just array[1], I just get the results of the users that have 1 and only 1 as their tag. I would like to get users that have 1 in their tags list even if they have something else. However, if I pass in something like [1,3], I want users that only have both of those.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want users having tags 1 and 3, and *only* those tags, you may use:

```sql
SELECT u.*, ARRAY_AGG(ut.tag_id) AS tags
FROM users u
INNER JOIN usertags ut ON u.id = ut.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING MIN(ut.tag_id) <> MAX(ut.tag_id) AND
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ut.tag_id NOT IN (1, 3)) = 0;
```

Comment: I think this query will return false positives, such as [1, 2, 3].

Comment: @TheImpaler I consider 1, 2, 3 to be a true positive, as it contains both the 1 and 3 tags.  Let the OP comment what it wants, usually it is the logic in my answer above.

Comment: Yeah, you may be right. Now I can't understand the question clearly anymore.

Comment: If an extra column is synthesized using string_agg , it can be equated with the desired value . Then in the final output that synthesized column can be discarded.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=319fa3fe17c6a1a27719a6178b63e2de